# Creating endless background without image

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a simple game with `Swift` and `SpriteKit`.
I want to add an endless background (vertically), I only found answers for background with images but I need to do it without image, only background color.
I thought about checking if the player is in the `frame.maxY`, if so, to move it back to the starting point, but I was wondering if there is a better idea.

```
//Does not matter which ring we chose as all ring's 'y' position is the same.
func moveBackgroundUp(){
    if ((mPlayer.position.y >= self.frame.maxY) || (mRingOne.position.y >= self.frame.maxY)) {
        mPlayer.position.y = 150 //mPlayers original starting point.
        for ring in mRings {
            ring.position.y = 350
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't move the background up, but make some code for when the camera is about to occupy space that your current background node does not, add a new background sprite to the scene, where it's origin is where the last one ends. This will create a seamless feel.

Comment: using one sprite would be good too. but pierce answer is good as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't just move a background up the screen, that' really isn't the way to go about it. What you should do is detect the position of the camera (assuming it moves with the player), and when it's position is about to occupy space outside of the occupied space of your current background sprite, add a new background sprite to the scene where the last one left off. Here is an example of how to do that with just a red sprite:

First add a property to the scene to track level position:

```
// To track the y-position of the level
var levelPositionY: CGFloat = 0.0
```

Now create a method to update your background:

```
func updateBackground() {
    let cameraPos = camera!.position
    if cameraPos.y > levelPositionY - (size.height * 0.55) {
        createBackground()
    }
}

func createBackground() {

    // Create a new sprite the size of your scene
    let backgroundSprite = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: size)
    backgroundSprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    backgroundSprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: levelPositionY)

    // Replace backgroundNode with the name of your backgroundNode to add the sprite to
    backgroundNode.addChild(backgroundSprite)
    levelPositionY += backgroundSprite.size.height
}
```

Now you want to call `updateBackground` inside your overridden `update(_:)` method:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    // All your other update code
    updateBackground()

}
```

Also, make sure to create an initial background when you first create the scene:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    createBackground()
}
```

**NOTE!** - It's important to set the custom anchor point for the background sprite for this code to work properly. An anchor of (0.5, 0) allows the background sprite to be anchored in the middle of the scene on the x-axis, but at the bottom of the scene on the y-axis. This allows you to easily stack one on top of the other.

**EDIT** - I forgot to mention that it's also a good idea to conserve resources and remove any background nodes that are outside the viewable area and won't be coming back in (i.e. a continuous scrolling game where you can't go backwards). You could do that by updating your `updateBackground` method above:

```
func updateBackground() {
    let cameraPos = camera!.position
    if cameraPos.y > levelPositionY - (size.height * 0.55) {
        createBackground()
    }

    // Make sure to change 'backgroundNode' to whatever the name of your backgroundNode is.
    for bgChild in backgroundNode.children {
        // This will convert the node's coordinates to scene's coordinates. See below for this function
        let nodePos = fgNode.convert(fgChild.position, to: self)
        if !isNodeVisible(bgChild, positionY: nodePos.y) {
            // Remove from it's parent node
            bgChild.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}

func isNodeVisible(_ node: SKNode, positionY: CGFloat) -> Bool {
    if !camera!.contains(node) {
        if positionY < camera!.position.y - size.height * 2.0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

So above you just loop through all the children inside your background node and detect if they are out of view, and if so remove them from the parent. Make sure to change my generic `backgroundNode` to whatever the name of your background node is.

Comment: @swiftnewbie - I forgot to mention that it's a good idea to also remove nodes from your scene once they're out of view and won't come back. Otherwise you'll end up allocating all your memory and your app will close if it's running for a long time. I will add an update to my answer to show you how. It's best programming practice. Good luck :)

Comment: Is there anything I should do? I have a problem of "found nil while unwrapping an optional value". on the updateBackground func, caused by the let cameraPos line.

Comment: @swiftnewbie - You need to make sure your scene has a `camera` node property. At the top of your class add `let cameraNode = SKCameraNode()`, then in `didMove(to view:)` add this: `addChild(cameraNode)`, then `camera = cameraNode` on a new line, and then `camera?.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)` one line below that. Should fix the problem. You're unwrapping an optional value of your scene's camera node which apparently you never actually instantiated.